# C# ASP.NET File.OpenRead from UNC path: "Access to path.....is denied."

Tags: c#, iis, file-io

I'm attempting to read a PDF from a UNC path, i.e. \10.32.16.24\repositories\repository0001\VOL00001\ktappb01_024655001_0.PDF

My virtual directory ASP.NET site is being run under IUSR_machine_name.
Has anonymous access enabled as well.

I gave IUSR_machine_name full rights to the UNC share and as I step through my ASP.NET page's code behind onto the File.OpenRead(filepath) method, it throws an exception: "Access to path \10.32.16.24\repositories\repository0001\VOL00001\ktappb01_024655001_0.PDF is denied".

I tried granting the ASPNET user full rights to the share as well with the same result.

At this point I'm completely lost for a resolution.

I'm running IIS6.

Comment: Is the ASPNET account a domain account, or an account on your local machine?

Also, you might get better responses on serverfault.com.

Comment: I added "Everyone" with all access on the share and it works now. So that tells me that it is indeed a permissions issue and that a different user is being impersonated, not my IUSR or ASPNET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the user by logging it. I'd made a stupid error in my code that wasn't giving me the result I was assuming I was going to get.

Answer (score 0):

On both machines security eventlog, check what user has been denied access. It is most likely a different user.

Comment: I set auditting up on the share, but it's not logging the failures in the security event log.
I added "Everyone" with all access on the share and it works now. 
So that tells me that it is indeed a permissions issue and that a different user is being impersonated, not my IUSR or ASPNET.